# Liquibase changeset reporting to be deleting tables, however tables are clearly not being removed

Tags: java, sql-server, liquibase

I am running the following changeset on an instance who's schema is completely managed by liquibase:

```
<changeSet author="aweigold" id="20120213-1">
    <delete tableName="domain_StudyListMap"/>
    <delete tableName="domain_StudyList"/>
</changeSet>
```

And I am able to validate that it runs, and that there are no other changesets executing afterwards:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [ID]
      ,[AUTHOR]
      ,[FILENAME]
      ,[DATEEXECUTED]
      ,[ORDEREXECUTED]
      ,[EXECTYPE]
      ,[MD5SUM]
      ,[DESCRIPTION]
      ,[COMMENTS]
      ,[TAG]
      ,[LIQUIBASE]
  FROM [VG3].[dbo].[DATABASECHANGELOG]
  ORDER BY ORDEREXECUTED DESC

ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, EXECTYPE, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, TAG, LIQUIBASE
20120213-1, aweigold, database/common-server_02.xml, 2012-02-14 09:58:46.700, 245, EXECUTED, 3:420703ba84d05a57da0e8afb0faa690d, Delete Data (x2), NULL, 2.0.3

(1 rows affected)
```

However my tables still exist:

```
SELECT
      name
  FROM VG3.sys.tables
  WHERE name = 'domain_StudyListMap' or
        name = 'domain_StudyList'

name
domain_StudyList
domain_StudyListMap

(2 rows affected)
```

I assume that there must be some sort of constraint or something in sql-server preventing the tables from being dropped, however I need some help on what I need to look for so I can identify what needs to be changed in my changeset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete` is used to delete data from the table.  What you want is `dropTable`